# What kind of program(s) cannot maintain its complexity structure when the program or data is partitioned?

Tags: operating-system, time-complexity, complexity-theory, partition

I received this question in my operating systems class and after some research I still cannot find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I understand complexity structure to be the min complexity (number of computation steps) necessary to compute the given level of partitioning of data or program.

The answers are is in the question, namely programs that need more steps to tackle partitioned data or processing units.

1. If data access pattern (granularity, scope, cardinality) necessitates access and integration of the results.
2. Accessing and integrating products of division of computation (Threads, Processes, Nodes) (IO, Integration)

programs that have X level complexity utilising indexed access to all the parts and granularities of data at the same time. If the data were partitioned more steps would be necessary to access and query partitions individually Y and still more to integrate W, resulting in f(X, Y, W) level of complexity depending on the level of integration and access.

One example would be programs that perform table join queries optimising searches by indexing (SQL joins). Such programs could not remain in the same complexity operate if the tables or columns were in different databases or nodes (NoSQL(Key value, Columnar ...)).

Another example would be a program calling (threads, processes, nodes) and combining the results. Calling the threads and combining the results would take more computation steps than doing it sequentially.

The question is a bit out of context you would do well do add context!